# how to execute code inside of image onload function before returning the result?

Tags: image, onload

I want to return code executed inside of image onload function. The code is :

```
function loadImage() {
  var data = null;
   var image = new Image();
   image.onload = function() {
     console.log("I am inside of image load function");
     data = "I am inside";
   }
   image.src="flower.jpg";
   console.log("I am outside of image load function");

   console.log(data);
   return data;
}
```

And the result in firefox console is :

```
I am outside of image load function
null
I am inside of image load function
```

What i want is, the above code should return the value of data assigned inside of image onload function i.e. i want the returned data to be "I am inside". i.e.

```
I am inside of image load function
I am outside of image load function
I am inside
```

What to do get to the desired result ?

or

How to execute the code inside of the image onload function first and then only outside of the function ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the example above is a boiled down sample of something else?

Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve but looking at your code do you understand why the null comes where it does?

data maybe null at the the point console.log(data) is executed because the image hasn't finished loading.

What do you want to happen when the image loads and can't you make it happen from within the unload even handler?

Comment: I want to return the data that is assigned inside of the image onload function but i always get null returned. How to achieve this ?

Comment: You can't return the data that's assigned in the unload function as the function will execute after the load image method returns. What you can do is pass a callback in that can be called from the unload function.